# Get Bounding Pixel Coordinates of Object from Image

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, image

I have ~ 500 images of hard disks rendered in blender and I am looking to separate the object from the environment. I was wondering if there was a way I could get the pixel coordinates of the object in the rendered image (a bounding polygon if you will) such that I could separate out the environment from the object.

[hard disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIXDZ.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIXDZ.png)

[hdd1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1Hco.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1Hco.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: how do the other images look like? are they all at the same location and all perfectly rectangle top view?

Comment: The other images are images of various HDDs and SSDs, rotated at various angles in the xy, yz and zx plane. All of their centroids (volumetric) are at the same location. I've added another image of a rotated hdd as an example

Comment: oh its an image sequence? that's going to be pretty hard to do, especially if u want it to perfectly find the edges of the hard disk to cut out background. u probably would need some AI to detect the moving object in the image sequence. or would it suffice to cut out the hard disk with 4 straight line cuts? which wud still leave a little of the background left. i assume that wont be enough but if it was then maybe camera tracking by putting in some tracking points for the 4 corners could do the trick and help find an algo with python to cut image

Comment: Yeah I figured, and even if I were to go that route, I wouldn't be able to get it with the precision I am looking for! I'm working around this problem by separating out the whole disk itself. I used a few suns to illuminate each object, removed all the materials so they are albedo textures, rendered them in blender and thresholded the image to separate the disks and all of their contents from the environment. Would definitely welcome a more elegant solution though!